# Use column defined from subquery in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use the value obtained from SEATS_RESERVED like so. The query below gives me an Invalid column name 'SEATS_RESERVED' error.

```
SELECT *,
SEATS_RESERVED =
(SELECT COUNT(UID)
FROM person WHERE person.RES_DATE = reservation_dates.RES_DATE 
AND person.ARCHIVE = 'FALSE')
FROM reservation_dates
WHERE TERM = ?
AND SEATS_RESERVED < MAX_SEATS;
```

Comment: if SEATS_RESERVED  is a variable declare it with`@`. for example: @SEATS_RESERVED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a derived field in the SELECT *and* reference it in the WHERE clause.

There are several options to deal with that, here is one with the least changes to your query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *,
  SEATS_RESERVED =
  (SELECT COUNT(UID)
  FROM person WHERE person.RES_DATE = reservation_dates.RES_DATE 
  AND person.ARCHIVE = 'FALSE')
  FROM reservation_dates
  WHERE TERM = ?
)
  AS data
WHERE SEATS_RESERVED < MAX_SEATS;
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to set SEATS_RESERVED equal to a value in your subquery, but you haven't declared SEATS_RESERVED yet. Also, where is MAX_SEATS defined?

How about this:

```
DECLARE @MAX_SEATS INT
SET @MAX_SEATS = <some integer>


SELECT *,
   (SELECT COUNT(UID) FROM person WHERE person.RES_DATE = reservation_dates.RES_DATE 
AND person.ARCHIVE = 'FALSE' HAVING COUNT(UID) < @MAX_SEATS;) AS SEATS_RESERVED
FROM reservation_dates
WHERE TERM = ?
```

Comment: It's not a variable. It's an alternative syntaxt to `SELECT *, (sub-query) AS SEATS_RESERVED FROM ...`.  And is appears that `MAX_SEATS` is a field in the `reservation_dates` table.